# Why is this an ARMA(1,1) model from reading the acf and pacf

Tags: time-series, arima, acf-pacf

the pacf cuts off around lag 7, and acf at 4, why is it a arma(1,1) model?[image]
[image]

Comment: Mixed models I have read can not always be easily found through the classical box jenkins approach. That is why grid searches have become more common.

Comment: They asked why the use of classical box jenkins identifies a specific model. I am saying don't use box jenkins to identify a mixed model which is what a 1,1 ARMA model is.